# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error for property of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is a problem with my project . I have a total price in my model and its going to sum all the products inside toyr cart and here is the property for model :

```
@property
def total(self):
    total = sum( i.price() for i in self.order_item.all())
    if self.discount:
        discount_price = (self.discount / 100) * total
        return int(total - discount_price)
    return self.total
```

self.discount is the discount of the order if it had and self.order_item is the related name for the items inside the order.

so the problem is when i try to get the total from this model , it give me an error :

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

And my code to get the total from the model is :

```
i = order_id
amount = get_object_or_404(Order , id = i)
```

Also i get the order_id from the url !

So what os wrong here . Hepl me please .

Comment: The property method is `self.total`. This line will invoke the property getter, which results in a recursion error as correctly noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not return `self.total`, since then you fetch the property a second time (and thus it will keep fetching the property). You should return the `total`, so:

```
@property
def total(self):
    total = sum( i.price() for i in self.order_item.all())
    if self.discount:
        discount_price = (self.discount / 100) * total
        return int(total - discount_price)
    #       ↓ use total, not self.total
    return total
```